# Using WiX Toolset -> Torch.exe with Azure DevOps Pipeline does not work

Tags: azure-devops, wix, azure-pipelines

I am using an Azure DevOps Services pipeline to create a setup. This pipeline creates the MSI and wixpdb. Then I call torch.exe in a command line script to create a patch from two different wixpdb's. This works locally without problems, but when I call torch.exe in a command line script in Azure DevOps Services Pipeline I get the following error:

> torch.exe : error TRCH0001 : A part of the path "C:\temp\Agent\4\s\test\udmonxof\udmonxof.cab" could not be found.

What can I do to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the problem as follows:

This helped me: https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/5778

I have added the following entries to the registry in a command line script:

> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\AppContext]
>   "Switch.System.DisableTempFileCollectionDirectoryFeature"="true"
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\AppContext]
>   "Switch.System.DisableTempFileCollectionDirectoryFeature"="true"

After that I called torch.exe and no error occurs anymore.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the project should generate three files, `.msi`, `.cab` and `.wixpdb` file.

For azure devops pipeline, it need these three files all exists, so that it can create patch successfully. But in your scenario, our system could not find `.cab` file there.

So, firstly, please ensure the `.cab` file was also generated successfully while it create the MSI and wixpdg file.

Assume there has one media argument in your `WXS` file, please make sure the `EmbedCab` value is **no**.

Sample:

```
<Media Id="1"
       Cabinet="media1.cab"
       EmbedCab="no"
       DiskPrompt="Disk 1"
       VolumeLabel="Disk1" />

<Media Id="2"
       Cabinet="media2.cab"
       EmbedCab="no"
       DiskPrompt="Disk 2" 
       VolumeLabel="Disk2" />
```